# Форматирование вывода данных в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как красиво вывести числа в несколько столбцов, чтобы они не скакали?

Код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(i + "  |  ");
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("{0, 7} | ", i);
        sum += i;
        count++;
        if (count == 8)
        {
            count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на следующее:

- Для выравнивания выдачи чисел используется строка формата `{0, 7}`. Подробнее: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Для сохранения столбцов от строки к строке, после каждых 8 чисел выдается перевод строки: `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось. Немного подправил, что бы мне нравилось, и все выглядит просто отлично.